# Building the asp.net project in VS 17 shows the error "Cannot load System.Threading.Tasks, Version= 4.0.0.0, " This file is corrupted and unreadable

Tags: asp.net

I am starting the ASP.NET project and while starting the project I face this issue

I have tried changing the System.Threading.Tasks file and replacing it, I have googled it but didn't find the exact solution I have reinstalled and repaired my Visual studio

[image]

Comment: Post error messages as text, please

Comment: Go to your webconfig and check if System.Threading.Task is there, also remove it from package.config and reinstall from nuget